# Vb.net Select statement ends ubruptly

Tags: vb.net, select, for-loop, checkbox

I'm having what i believe is a simple problem with a simple fix that I cannot see. I have a form in which the user selects multiple checkboxes for a selection. [image: Checkbox Selection]

When you user presses the submit button I have an array that I want to hold which numbers are being used (1 - 12). My array is stored in a module.

```
Module MyVariables

    Public NumbersUsing(11) As Integer

End Module
```

Here is the code for my select statment, I'm going to cut off the repitious part for simplicity and shortness.

```
Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
       Handles SubmitBtn.Click

Select Case True
    Case CheckBox1.Checked
        For i As Integer = 0 To 11
            If NumbersUsing(i) = Nothing Then
                NumbersUsing(i) = 1
                Exit For
            Else
                i += 1
            End If
        Next

    Case CheckBox2.Checked
        For i As Integer = 0 To 11
            If NumbersUsing(i) = Nothing Then
                NumbersUsing(i) = 2
                Exit For
            Else
                i += 1
            End If
        Next

    Case CheckBox3.Checked
        For i As Integer = 0 To 11
            If NumbersUsing(i) = Nothing Then
                NumbersUsing(i) = 3
                Exit For
            Else
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
 ...

  End Select

    For i = 0 To 11
        MessageBox.Show(NumbersUsing(i)) 'To test which numbers have been entered.
        i += 1
    Next

End Sub
```

All i get in the messagebox are basically 1's and 0's and it doesn't go past the first case statement check. **It doesn't check ANY of the other case statements except for the first one.** I don't know why it's doing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to do with all these loops; but the Select Case statement is exclusive, like an `If then... else if then...` if the first condition is met the next one is not analysed. Can you please explain exactly what you want to accomplish?

Comment: `Else ... i += 1` will trunate how many times each loops goes by half.  get rid of it.  Also, the EXIT for in each CASE means only the first array index is set (if it was nothing)

Comment: That's what i figured, but i wasn't entirely sure. I suppose individual if statements are needed. I'm trying to make it look at each checkbox. If the checkbox is checked then it sets the value associated with that checkbox to the earliest index in the array.

Comment: put the FOR loop in a procedure can call it for each check. no need to repeat the code.

Comment: @Plutonix What i'm doing with the for loop is that Each checkbox represents a value of 1 through 12. And i'm making it so that whichever boxes are checked, they go to the first "available" index of the array. They don't overwrite any array indexes and i don't set them to an index with blank indexes before it. Make sense?

Comment: they do EXACTLY the same thing except for the value it sets (1,2,3) just make that a param to a called proc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first `Case CheckBox1.Checked` is true, the rest of the `Case`s will not be run. From [the documentation for `Select...Case` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cy37t14y.aspx):

> If *testexpression* matches any **Case** *expressionlist* clause, the statements following that **Case** statement run up to the next **Case**, **Case Else**, or **End Select** statement. Control then passes to the statement following **End Select**.

Answer (score 0):

A list would probably work better here. See if something like this helps:

```
Dim NumbersUsing As New List(Of Integer)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'I assumed you're using a GroupBox to hold the checkboxes
    For Each cb As CheckBox In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        If cb.Checked Then
            'As long as all the checkboxes are in the pattern you've shown _
            'SubString(8) will isolate the index of the checkboxes
            Dim index As Integer = Integer.Parse(cb.Name.Substring(8))
            NumbersUsing.Add(index)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```